# Pandas dataframe column remove string before the first specific character

Tags: python, pandas, string, split, strip

I have a dataframe df with an 'Address' column. I would like to remove the street address (which theoretically is the part before the first comma) and keep on the city level address.

df

```
Address
777 Brockton Avenue, Abington, MA 2351
30 Memorial Drive, Avon, MA 2322
250 Hartford Avenue, Bellingham, MA 2019
700 Oak Street, Brockton, MA 2301
66-4 Parkhurst Rd, Chelmsford, MA 1824
```

Desired df

```
Address
Abington, MA 2351
Avon, MA 2322
Bellingham, MA 2019
Brockton, MA 2301
Chelmsford, MA 1824
```

I tried this following code but it remove all strings before all comma. I would like to only remove string before the first comma in the column.

```
df['Address'] = df['Address'].str.split(',').str.get(-1)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add parameter `n=1` for split by first comma:

```
df['Address'] = df['Address'].str.split(',', n=1).str.get(-1)
print (df)
                Address
0     Abington, MA 2351
1         Avon, MA 2322
2   Bellingham, MA 2019
3     Brockton, MA 2301
4   Chelmsford, MA 1824
```